# Link to fan-page with app_data parameter removes the app_data parameter

Tags: facebook, sharing

I have a FB app in an `iframe` on a Facebook fan-page. If I create a URL linking to that page, and that URL contains an `app_data` parameter, like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page/123?sk=app_456&app_data=mydata
```

Then post that in my FB feed, FB strips the `app_data` parameter, reverting to the canonical URL for the fan page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page/123?sk=app_456
```

Which isn't what I want.

I would consider this a bug, as the state of the application is part of the "canonical" state of the fan page, but for now: Any way to get around this?

I have thought about making the bookmark to my own page:

```
https://facebook.mysite.com/pages/My-Page/123?sk=app_456&app_data=mydata
```

and dynamically generate a page with all the OpenGraph tags from the corresponding FB page (to make FB sharing work), and a redirect to the fan page (to get the user to the right place) - but this requires either (a) scraping FB for those OpenGraph tags or (b) accessing the graph.facebook.com api programmatically in a crawl-like fashion, and I don't know what FB thinks of that.

Answer (score 2):

G'Day Leo, might be a bit of a hack but seems to work. I link my app_data onto a separately hosted URL and redirect back to Facebook with it.

So my URL I share is: https://externaldomain.com/deeplinker.aspx?data=stuff

Then response a redirect which is: https://www.facebook.com/[pageurl]?sk=[app]&app_data=[data]

With [data] = stuff